# Is this sentence grammatically correct? “dared bid”

Tags: grammar

After reading a text, I came across this sentence

> Nobody dared **bid** on the priceless antique vase.

Is this sentence grammatically correct ?
Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb 'dare', with the meaning in your example, can be followed either with a 'to infinitive' (e.g. 'dared to bid') or the bare form of a verb ('dared bid'). Either form is grammatical.

> Dare also means ‘to be brave enough or rude enough to do something’.
>   With this meaning, it can be used as an ordinary main verb which can
>   be followed by a to-infinitive or an infinitive without to. Less
>   commonly, it can be used as a semi-modal verb followed by an
>   infinitive without to.
>
> Affirmative statement If Sally dares (to) go there again, she’ll be in
>   big trouble! (ordinary verb)
>
> Negative statement He doesn’t dare (to) go there. (ordinary verb)
>
> No one dares (to) go there. (ordinary verb)
>
> No one dare go there. (semi-modal verb)

[Dare (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/dare)